# Two KeyListeners on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

Is it a good practice to add few listeners for JComponent in different part of code? Should I create one bigger listener?

For example I have JTextField, I noticed that both KeyListeners are called.

```
 JTextField textField = new JTextField();
  textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
  {
     @Override
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
     {

     }

     @Override
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
     {

     }

     @Override
     public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
     {
        something();
     }
  });

  textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
  {
     @Override
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
     {

     }

     @Override
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
     {

     }

     @Override
     public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
     {
        somethingElse();
     }
  });
```

Comment: its just about one DocumentListener/Filter, don't use KeyListener

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use KeyAdapter instead. This class has empty methods, so you only need to override what is non empty. Also think about error handling, i.e. surround your handler's content with a try-catch block.

Comment: Well, it's bad practice to use `KeyListener` with text components.  Is it good practice to use multiple listeners on the same component, generally yes. Is it good practice to use single use listeners with components, yes. Is it good practice to have one big listener, IMHO, no. The reasoning is, you want to create small units of work that do a single, isolated job.  Sure you might be able to abstract a listener which would allow you to re-use, but having a single monolithic listener is just a maintenance nightmare

Comment: As already written by @mKorbel if you want to monitore text changes in a text component you should use [DocumentListener or DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you answer this question that I can give you correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's bad practice to use `KeyListener` (generally, but especially) with text components.

- Is it good practice to use multiple listeners on the same component, generally yes.
- Is it good practice to use single use listeners with components, yes.
- Is it good practice to have one big listener, IMHO, no. The reasoning is, you want to create small units of work that do a single, isolated job. Sure you might be able to abstract a listener which would allow you to re-use, but having a single monolithic listener is just a maintenance nightmare

Most listener interfaces tend to have "adapter" class, which are just concrete implementations of the listener interface without any functionality, so you can pick and choose the methods you actually want to use