# Exception handling in JTextField

Tags: java, user-interface, exception

I am writing a restaurant application. [image]

In this part, in order to add cook, user needs to enter cook's name in a nameTextField and cook's salary in a salaryTextField and at the name part I want to prevent the user from entering numbers and at the salary part I want to prevent the user from entering words. For salary part I tried to use exception handling but couldn't really succeed.

```
class AddButtonInCookClick implements ActionListener{

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String name = (String)nameTextFieldCook.getText();
                    double salary = new Double(0.0);
                    try {
                        salary = Double.parseDouble(salaryTextField.getText());
                    }catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }
                    restaurant.getEmployees().add(new Cook(id, name, salary));
                    id++;
                    JOptionPane cookOptionPane = new JOptionPane();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(cookOptionPane, "Cook added succesfully.");

                }   
            }
            addButtonInCook.addActionListener(new AddButtonInCookClick());
```

Even though the program doesn't crush. I still can't make user enter numbers for salary part. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I believe you need a `KeyListener` and on every key press check for the input and show error right away. Coming to your code you are just logging exception. That wouldn’t stop the user entering alphabets

Comment: You have several ways to achieve this, including, but not limited to: [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html), [InputVerifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) and [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).

Comment: @SunilDabburi: and that is a *very* bad recommendation. Much better to go with Abra's suggestion as they are safer and much more robust. How will a KeyListener work when the user copies and pastes data into the text field? And do you know that use of a KeyListener risks causing dysfunction in how the JTextField works? Again, do not recommend this.

Comment: For more on why you should avoid KeyListeners and why you *should* follow @Abra's advice, please read [MadProgrammer's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34672396/522444).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict input solely to numerals by using [`JFormattedTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) in lieu of a normal `JTextField`.

Sample code:

```
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
  JFormattedTextField salaryFormattedTextField;
  NumberFormat numberFormat;
  NumberFormatter numberFormatter;

  public Test()
  {
    numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    // delete line if you want to see commas or periods grouping numbers based on your locale
    numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);           

    numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
    numberFormatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);
    // delete line if you want to allow user to enter characters outside the value class.
    // Deleting the line would allow the user to type alpha characters, for example.
    // This pretty much defeats the purpose of formatting
    numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);

    salaryFormattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);

    this.add(salaryFormattedTextField);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Test test = new Test();
    s.pack();
    s.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

The alternative, using the code structure you already have, is to throw up a JOptionPane when the input doesn't parse correctly.

```
try
{
    salary = Double.parseDouble(salaryTextField.getText());
    restaurant.getEmployees().add(new Cook(id, name, salary));
    id++;
    JOptionPane cookOptionPane = new JOptionPane();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(cookOptionPane, "Cook added succesfully.");
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex)
{
    JOptionPane cookFailPane = new JOptionPane();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(cookFailPane , "Could not add cook. Please enter salary using only numeric input.");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```